# PyLint bad-whitespace Configuration

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

Is there a way to configure the checks for the `bad-whitespace` checks in PyLint? I can currently disable checking but I would much rather enforce a whitespace convention instead of disabling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options you could use:

1. Globally disable the bad-whitespace warning:

   ```
   pylint --disable=C0326
   ```
2. Use a Pylint configuration file:

   ```
   pylint --rcfile=/path/to/config.file
   ```

   This is what you would put in the config file to disable the bad-whitespace warning:

   ```
   disable=C0326
   ```

Answer (score 5):

The .pylintrc file does offer limited editing of whitespace rules, using the attribute `no-space-check`:

```
# List of optional constructs for which whitespace checking is disabled. `dict-
# separator` is used to allow tabulation in dicts, etc.: {1  : 1,\n222: 2}.
# `trailing-comma` allows a space between comma and closing bracket: (a, ).
# `empty-line` allows space-only lines.
no-space-check=
```

Might be more options in the near-future, though.

Comment: Pylint 2.6: The no-space-check option has been removed, it's no longer possible to consider empty line like a trailing-whitespace by using clever options http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.6.html .

Answer (score 1):

The ID of `bad-whitespace` convention check is `C0326` from pylint 1.1.0 onwards. You can use this code in the *.pylintrc* config file to enable/disable the `bad-whitespace` check.

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
enable=C0326
```

or

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=C0326
```