# Pylint VsCode Disable Warning

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I have .pylintrc in my folder with this content:

```
disable=print-statement,
        parameter-unpacking,
        unpacking-in-except,
        old-raise-syntax,
        backtick,
        long-suffix,
        old-ne-operator,
        old-octal-literal,
        import-star-module-level,
        non-ascii-bytes-literal,
        raw-checker-failed,
        bad-inline-option,
        bad-whitespace
```

However, when typing in VSCode I always see "bad-whitespace" warnings

[image]

Comment: Disabling pylint in vscode needs to be done in the .vscode/settings.json file - for example  `"pylint.args": ["--disable", "redefined-outer-name"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can disable by adding it to message control in config file C0326 is for bad-whitespace

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=C0326
```

more info here
[PyLint bad-whitespace Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198054/pylint-bad-whitespace-configuration)

Comment: What about in user .json?